# ASP.Net Core 2 Razor AJAX GET with parameter?

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

How can i make an AJAX GET-Request in my ASP.Net Core 2 Razor Application with a parameter i want to pass to the receiving function.

For example i have a `Select`-Field inside my HTML. Depending on which value was selected i want to receive a list of values. For this i wrote an AJAX-GET-Request this way.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Index?handler=Test2',
    contentType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log('Data received: ');
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

So the call works nearly perfect. It calls the `OnGetTest2()` inside my Code-Behind-Page (Index.cshtml.cs). My `OnGetTest2()` looks like:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult OnGetTest2(string id)
{
     // Some code logic to get the needed values i want to post back
     Console.WriteLine("Received id: " + id);
     return new JsonResult(9999); // e.g. 9999 as return value
}
```

But i'm stuck on how to pass the value of the selected option of my `Select`-Element with my AJAX-Call above to my `OnGetTest2()`-Function. How can i get it work? Actually i will receive the "9999", so the AJAX-Call is working, but i need to pass the selected value the `OnGetTest2()`-Function.

Comment: You method expects a parameter named `id` but your passing a value named `handler`. And always use `'@Url.Action()` to generate your urls. = its `url  '@Url.Action("OnGetTest2", "yourConrollerName")',` and your add the `data: { id: yourValue },` option to pass the value (and `url: '/Index?handler=Test2',` could never hit the `OnGetTest2()` method unless you have some specific roue definitions, so not sure how your claiming it does)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic ways to do this.

Option 1: Using a query string.  Your ajax will be basically what you have, you set a url variable `handler` equal to "Test2".  In the controller use `Request.Query["handler"]` to get the value.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult OnGetTest2()
{
    var id = Request.Query["handler"];
    // ... more stuff

}
```

Options 2:  Route attributes.  Route attributes are awesome!  Change your url in the ajax to be `url = '/Index/Test2'` and then use this in your controller:

```
[HttpGet, Route("index/{id}")]
public IActionResult OnGetTest2(string id)
{
    // id already has the value in it
    // ... do stuff

}
```

If you want something other than a string, like an int, use something like this.

```
[HttpGet, Route("index/{id:int}")]
public IActionResult OnGetTest2(int id)
{

    // ... do stuff

}
```

Comment: when i do it like you second solution "Route attributes" i receive the whole html page as result. so something is wrong here. and just for notice Test2 is not my variable i want to pass? handler=Test2 indicates which of my OnGetXXX() functions will be called and here in my example the OnGetTest2().

Comment: If you are getting a whole page back that is because the method returns a `View()`.  Your url in the ajax is '/Index?handler=Test2' which by default in .net is going to route to the index method with a url variable handler equal to the value of "Test2".  That is just how .net works.  If you want to route to `/OnGetTest2` then your url in ajax should be that.  Then simply change the route attribute as desired.

Comment: Just a quick clarification about .net mvc routing.  Default routing is `www.mysite.com/controllerName/actionName`.  So a url of /home/index goes to the index action in the home controller.  If you want the OnGetTest2 action in the home controller then use /home/OnGetTest2.  You can use route attributes to add special routing.

Comment: So i have to call: „/Index/OnGetTest2/myValueToPass“ Right? I will look at this tomorrow

Comment: My guess is that you are inside the HomeController right?  So then the page is "/home/OnGetTest2/{value}".  But, you can use the route attribute to make it what ever you want.

Comment: i tried it again but no success. I get no result - the function will not be called. Have i to do something else like some configuration stuff? Or could you provide a small working example?

Comment: you're missing the closing parentheses on the Route("index/{id:int}"). Tried to edit it but stackoverflow required more then 2 edits :p

Answer (score 2):

First get the value of your Select-Field

```
var SelectFieldValue =  $("#Select-Field-ID").val();
```

then send it to action via ajax call like :

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Index?id=' + SelectFieldValue,
    contentType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log('Data received: ');
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending the string "Test2" as the parameter you need to declare a variable that is set equal to the selected item.

```
var e = document.getElementById("ddl");
var item= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

OR JQuery

```
var item = $('#ddl').val();
```

Then you can send this via AJAX

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/Index?id=' + item,
   contentType: 'json',
   success: function (result) {
    console.log('Data received: ');
    console.log(result);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining your method structure the way it is in your question, you can easily construct your ajax GET request like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/Index?handler=Test2&id=' + id,
    contentType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log('Data received: ');
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

Notice the URL adds the id to the query. The query has started from '/Index?...', so you are simply adding a parameter to the query here. The first query is a handler which Razor will handle to find the method, then any other query you add afterwards, the compiler maps it to the parameters of that method as though you were writing a normal URL with queries.

You do not need the routes attribute or manually get the Id from the Request in the controller anymore. What you have is just fine.